# Trouble with logging into phpMyAdmin on an Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

Okay, I'm stumped... I've reinstalled this instance 3 times now and I can't seem to figure it out. I've pretty much followed this tutorial http://calebogden.com/wordpress-on-linux-in-the-amazon-cloud-with-mac/ word for word with one exception, I installed phpmyadmin v3.5.5 from the phpMyAdmin website.

Also, instead of installing it though Terminal, I did it with Coda, drag and dropped into the /var/www/html folder through SFTP.

The EC2 Instance is an Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09 64 bit.

The problem:

I went to /phpMyAdmin/setup/index.php
created a "New server" with a cookie Authentication type

I only changed the "Verbose name of this server" and "Password for config auth."

Now when I go to /phpMyAdmin/setup/index.php to log in, and type:

UN: Root
PW: mypassword (Which I'm using the one I created when I installed mySQL)

/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password ‘SUPERSECUREPASSWORD’

I keep getting this error: 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I know I'm typing the password in just as I typed it in terminal. Sorry for the long post for such a simple question, I just wanted to be as detailed as possible in case I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: **SUPERSECUREPASSWORD** that's pretty super secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a straight forward tutorial that worked.

https://gist.github.com/1105007